# Filtering (or displaying) certain messages in MS Outlook using AppleScript

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript, filtering

I want to see emails (filtered) in MS outlook with a certain word in subject (e g Deal)

Wrote this script

```
set theMessages to {}
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theFolder to inbox 
    set theMessages to every message of theFolder whose subject contains "deal"
    set selected messages to theMessages
end tell
return theMessages
```

The result is :

> {incoming message id 104829 of application "Microsoft Outlook", incoming message id 104822 of application "Microsoft Outlook", incoming message id 104535 of application "Microsoft Outlook", incoming message id 103995 of application "Microsoft Outlook"}

but nothing is filtered in Outlook itself

how can I do it?

Comment: `set selection to theMessages`. As an aside, your verbiage is confused. The 'filtering' occurs in setting the contents of the list, not in your selection. The selecting is a separate act.

Comment: I may mistaken one action fro another. I would like to see the list of messages in the folder Income with the subject which contains "deal"

Comment: set theMessages to {}
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
 set theFolder to inbox
 set selected folder to theFolder
 set theMessages to every message of theFolder whose subject contains "COFED15733"
 try
  set selection to theMessages
 end try
end tell
return theMessages



this one does the same

Comment: Works for me. I'm using outlook 14.7 if that makes a difference. Two things… I would not use `try` at all here as it may obscure what is happening. Use it when your commands may generate an error that you wish to handle. Second, comment out everything after the last `set theMessage…` line and see what its result is. For me, I get a list that contains the desired messages, like so: `{outgoing message id 1 of application "Microsoft Outlook", outgoing message id 3 of application "Microsoft Outlook"}`. NB I'm using the drafts folder, hence the outgoing messages.

Comment: i got the same result as yours. it works but not the way i want. 
if you make keystroke "F" using {shift down, command down}, then keystorke cmd+v with DEAL in clipboards, then you get what i wanted. But I do not like to use keystrokes.

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't think that outlook offers a non-ui way to script that. The closest thing might be to create a new folder and dump the matching messages into it. Then you would see only those messages. After you could either manually move them or script something to return them to another folder.